# Having trouble with callback return statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback

Having a little trouble with skipping a callbacks returns. Here is the question:

> Write a function, `tap`, which accepts an array, `items`, and a callback function, cb. The callback function should be invoked on the array and then the returned value should be the array regardless of what the callback returns.

My Attempt:

```
function tap(items, cb){
  let result = items.map(cb)
  return result;
}
```

Samples:

```
console.log(tap([1, 2, 3], function (items) {
  items.pop();
})).reverse();  // [2,1]

console.log(tap(["a", "b", "c"], function (items) {
  return items[0];
}));  // ["a","b","c"]
```

When I put in this code, I'm hoping it will map the callback functions to the items array.

I received the following for each test case:

```
a. TypeError: items.pop is not a function
b. [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: The argument to the callback is each element of the array, not the whole array.

Comment: Also your `.map()` callback must have a `return` statement.

Comment: Your instructions are a little ambiguous, but I took it as meaning the callback should accept the entire array as an argument, not each individual item as you are doing.

Comment: It's nothing to do with your `return`. The issue is that you're passing an array of numbers in, then calling `map` on it and passing in `cb` as the mapping function, then using `item.pop()` on what `cb` receives -- but that `item` is a *number*, not an array.

Comment: in fact, assuming the "samples" you give were provided as test cases, they confirm my reading - the callback should be called on the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions don't say anyting about mapping the function, you're just supposed to invoke it on the array as a whole.

Since you're supposed to return the original array, you don't need to assign the callback result to a variable. Just return `items`.

You also need to call `reverse()` on the result returned by `tap()`. You're calling it on the result of `console.log()`, but it doesn't return anything.

```js
function tap(items, cb){
  cb(items);
  return items;
}

console.log(tap([1, 2, 3], function (items) {
  items.pop();
}).reverse());  // [2,1]

console.log(tap(["a", "b", "c"], function (items) {
  return items[0];
}));  // ["a","b","c"]
```